# Separate real and imaginary part of $\arccos(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, hyperbolic-functions

Beginning with

$$i \cos \left[ \frac{1}{n} \arccos \left( \frac{i}{\epsilon} \right) + \frac{m \pi}{n} \right]$$

where $m,n \in \mathbf{Z}$, $\epsilon >0$, $\epsilon \in \mathbf{R}$ and $i$ is the imaginary unit, I would like to obtain separately the real and imaginary part of the cosine argument:

(1)

$$\frac{1}{n} \arccos \left( \frac{i}{\epsilon} \right) + \frac{m \pi}{n} = x + iy$$

By simply applying the [definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseCosine.html):

(2)

$$\frac{1}{n} \arccos \left( \frac{i}{\epsilon} \right) = \frac{\pi}{2n} + i \frac{1}{n} \ln \left[ \frac{1}{\epsilon} (\sqrt{1 + \epsilon^2} - 1) \right]$$

Similarly, if we apply the [definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseSine.html) of complex $\arcsin$, we obtain:

$$\arcsin \left( \frac{i}{\epsilon} \right) = -i \ln \left[ \frac{1}{\epsilon} (\sqrt{1 + \epsilon^2} - 1) \right]$$

Remembering (as stated [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseHyperbolicSine.html)) that $$\mathrm{arsinh}(z) = -i\arcsin(iz)$$ we obtain

$$\mathrm{arsinh} \left( \frac{1}{\epsilon} \right) = - \ln \left[ \frac{1}{\epsilon} (\sqrt{1 + \epsilon^2} - 1) \right]$$

So we can write

$$x + iy = \frac{m \pi}{n} + \frac{\pi}{2n} + i\frac{1}{n} \ln \left[ \frac{1}{\epsilon} (\sqrt{1 + \epsilon^2} - 1) \right]$$

$$x + iy = \frac{\pi}{2} \left( \frac{2m + 1}{n} \right) - i\frac{1}{n} \mathrm{arsinh} \left( \frac{1}{\epsilon} \right) = \frac{\pi}{2} \left( \frac{2m - 1}{n} \right) - i\frac{1}{n} \mathrm{arsinh} \left( \frac{1}{\epsilon} \right)$$

But the correct result should be

(3)

$$x + iy = \frac{\pi}{2} \left( \frac{2m - 1}{n} \right) + i\frac{1}{n} \mathrm{arsinh} \left( \frac{1}{\epsilon} \right)$$

So, are there any errors? How to obtain (3) from (1)?

Comment: One error is in the relation of $\mathrm{arsinh}$ and $\ln$, for reel $x,\epsilon$ we have (http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.37.E37)
$$\mathrm{arsinh}(x) = \ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$$
so in your case
$$\mathrm{arsinh} \left( \frac{1}{\epsilon} \right) = \ln \left[ \frac{1}{\epsilon} (\sqrt{1 + \epsilon^2} + 1) \right]$$

Comment: @gammatester ok, but also the relation (presented [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseHyperbolicSine.html)) $$\mathrm{arsinh}(z) = -i\arcsin(iz)$$ holds and it means $$\mathrm{arsinh} \left( \frac{1}{\epsilon} \right) = -i\arcsin \left( \frac{i}{\epsilon} \right)$$. Moreover, $$\arcsin \left( \frac{i}{\epsilon} \right) = -i\ln\left[ \frac{1}{\epsilon} (\sqrt{1 + \epsilon^2} - 1) \right]$$. So $$\mathrm{arsinh} \left( \frac{1}{\epsilon} \right) = -\ln\left[ \frac{1}{\epsilon} (\sqrt{1 + \epsilon^2} - 1) \right]$$ and our relations bring to different results. How is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$i \cos \left( \frac{1}{n} \cos^{-1} \left( \frac{i}{\epsilon} \right) + \frac{m \pi}{n} \right)=i\cos\left(\frac{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{i}{\epsilon}\right)+m\pi}{n}\right)=$$

$$i\cos\left(\frac{\sec^{-1}\left(-i\epsilon\right)+m\pi}{n}\right)=i\cos\left(\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-i\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)}{n}+ \frac{m\pi}{n}\right)=$$

$$i\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}-\frac{i\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)}{n}+ \frac{m\pi}{n}\right)=$$

$$i\cos\left(\frac{\pi+2m\pi}{2n}-\frac{i*csch^{-1}(\epsilon)}{n}\right)=$$

$$i\cos\left(\frac{\pi+2m\pi}{2n}-\frac{csch^{-1}(\epsilon)}{n}i\right)$$

---

$$\frac{\pi+2m\pi}{2n}-\frac{csch^{-1}(\epsilon)}{n}i=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{2m-1}{n}\right)-\frac{\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)}{n}i=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{2m-1}{n}\right)-i\frac{1}{n}\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)$$

Comment: First of all thank you. Your final result, anyway, seems quite different with respect to $$x + iy = \frac{\pi}{2} \left( \frac{2m - 1}{n} \right) + i\frac{1}{n} \mathrm{arsinh} \left( \frac{1}{\epsilon} \right)$$. Is it possible to express your result this way? (I am obviously talking about the quantity inside the brackets)

Comment: @BowPark You're Welcome! I've tried to check your answer and my answer and it shows that it's equal to each other, but I'll check it further for you!

Comment: Thank you! Maybe the matter is just about how to transform $\mathrm{csch}^{-1}$ into $\mathrm{arsinh} $. I didn't find an explicit relation between them

Comment: @BowPark I'll put my results in my answer when I've found them!

Comment: @BowPark I've done it and yes it is equal!!!

Comment: Sorry for my delay. Trying to repeat your steps, and applying the definitions, I found $$\sec^{-1}(-i\epsilon) = \frac{\pi}{2} + i \ln \left[ \frac{1}{\epsilon} (\sqrt{1 + \epsilon^2} - 1) \right]$$ and $$\sinh^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{\epsilon} \right) = \ln \left[ \frac{1}{\epsilon} (\sqrt{1 + \epsilon^2} + 1) \right]$$ The same expression is obtained in the comments to my question. So, a relation between $$\sec^{-1}(-i\epsilon)$$ and $$\sinh^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{\epsilon} \right)$$ cannot be immediately found and the second line of your answer seems wrong. Or did you use some trick?

Comment: @BowPark Yes there is relation between them. In my answer I suggest: 

$$\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{i}{\epsilon}\right)=\sec^{-1}\left(-i\epsilon\right)$$

There I used the relation: $\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{i}{a}\right)=\sec^{-1}\left(-ia\right)$

To go from $\sec^{-1}(x)$ to $\sinh^{-1}(x)$ I used:

$$\sec^{-1}\left(-ia\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-i\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)$$

So we can use that in your question:

$$\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{i}{\epsilon}\right)=\sec^{-1}\left(-i\epsilon\right)=0.5 \pi-i\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)$$

So there is a relation between $\sec(x)$ and $\sinh(x)$.

Comment: «To go from $\sec^{−1}(x)$ to $\sinh^{−1}(x)$ I used:
$$\sec^{−1}(−ia)=\frac{\pi}{2}− i \sinh^{−1}\left( \frac{1}{a} \right)$$»
Yes, I know. But how can this relation be proved? This is the reason why I separately wrote the expressions of $\sec^{-1}(-i\epsilon)$ and $\sinh^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{\epsilon} \right)$ in my previous comment: I didn't succeed to prove that relation.

Comment: First of all we have to know a few things:

$$\sec(x)=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$$
$$\sec^{-1}(x)=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
$$\sinh(x)=\frac{1}{csch(x)}=\frac{1}{\frac{2e^x}{-1+e^{2x}}}=-\frac{1+e^{2x}}{2e^{x}}$$
$$\sinh^{-1}(x)=\ln\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)=-i\sin^{-1}(ix)$$

Comment: @BowPark Proof: $\sec^{-1}(-ix)=\frac{\pi}{2}-i\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$:

$$\sec^{-1}(-ix)=\frac{\pi}{2}-i\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\rightarrow$$
$$\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{-ix}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-i\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{-ix}\right)-\frac{\pi}{2}=-i\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-icsch^{-1}(x)=-i\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-i\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=-i\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

Q.E.D.

Comment: First of all and anyway thanks for your help. I found that
$$\sinh^{-1} (x) = \ln \left(x + \sqrt{1 + x^2} \right)$$
but
$$\sin^{-1}(ix) =  -i \ln \left(-x + \sqrt{1 + x^2} \right)$$
so the relation
$$\sinh^{-1} (x) = -i \sin^{-1}(ix)$$
is wrong and I suppose it is important for your steps. I updated just today my question with this observation. Do you agree?

Comment: @BowPark You're welcome buddy! The relation that you updated in your question is TRUE!! I've proved it for myself and Mathematica tells me it also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25623/discussion-between-bowpark-and-jan-eerland).

Comment: @BowPark I'm sorry I can't open the chat I don't know why! But I can give you my email-adress or phone-number so you can contact me! email to: janeerland27041997@gmail.com

Comment: Don't worry. If we can't solve it in the next comment, we will switch to e-mail! (I prefer here because formulas are formatted, and I have just one more question). Now I proved the identity $\sinh^{-1} (x) = -i \sin^{-1}(ix)$ and you were right, it is true. But I noticed that your final result is the same as mine: $$\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{2m-1}{n}\right)-i\frac{1}{n}\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)$$. The result I had is instead $$\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{2m-1}{n}\right)+i\frac{1}{n}\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)$$. What do you think? May it be wrong?

Comment: It has to be minus, I can proof it if you want!?

Comment: No, thank you. We obtained the same result following different procedures. Maybe the "reference" result I have is not correct. Feel free to delete the previous comments, if they make some confusion. You gave a great help!

Comment: @BowPark It is me a pleasure Buddy! You're welcome! With questions you can always ask me